# how to stack the keys from nasted dict and to flatten it

Tags: python, dictionary

I had a task to flatten nested dict, which was easy. This is my code for that:

```
class Simple:

    def __init__(self):
        self.store_data = {}

    def extract_data(self, config):
        for key in config:
            if isinstance(config[key], dict):
                self.extract_data(config[key])
            else:
                self.store_data[{key}] = config[key]
        return self.store_data
```

This was my intput:

```
input = {
    'k1_lv1': {
        'k1_lv2': 'v1_lv2', 'k2_lv2': 'v2_lv2'},
    'k2_lv1': 'v1_lv1',
    'k3_lv1': {
         'k1_lv2': 'v1_lv2', 'k2_lv2': 'v2_vl2'},
    'k4_lv1': 'v1_lv1',
}
```

and this was my output (imagine that the keys are unique):

```
output = {
    'k1_lv2': 'v1_lv2', 'k2_lv2': 'v2_lv2', 
    'k2_lv1': 'v1_lv1',
    'k1_lv2': 'v1_lv2', 'k2_lv2': 'v2_vl2',
    'k4_lv1': 'v1_lv1'
}
```

but now my task has been changed and my output has to become like this:

```
output = {
    'k1_lv1_k1_lv2': 'v1_lv2',
    'k1_lv1_k2_lv2': 'v2_lv2',
    'k2_lv1': 'v1_lv1',
    'k3_lv1_k1_lv2': 'v1_lv2',
    'k3_lv1_k2_lv2': 'v2_vl2',
    'k4_lv1': 'v1_lv1'
}
```

so I have to not only flatten the nested dict, but have to save the keys of nested dicts.
I tried to achieve that output but I am failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion for the task:

```py
dct = {
    "k1_lv1": {"k1_lv2": "v1_lv2", "k2_lv2": "v2_lv2"},
    "k2_lv1": "v1_lv1",
    "k3_lv1": {"k1_lv2": "v1_lv2", "k2_lv2": "v2_vl2"},
    "k4_lv1": "v1_lv1",
}


def flatten(d, path=""):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            yield from flatten(v, (path + "_" + k).strip("_"))
    else:
        yield (path, d)


out = dict(flatten(dct))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "k1_lv1_k1_lv2": "v1_lv2",
    "k1_lv1_k2_lv2": "v2_lv2",
    "k2_lv1": "v1_lv1",
    "k3_lv1_k1_lv2": "v1_lv2",
    "k3_lv1_k2_lv2": "v2_vl2",
    "k4_lv1": "v1_lv1",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you loop through the keys using input.keys() and then stack keys using

```py
output['{}_{}'.format(key_level1, key_level2]]= input['key_level1']['key_level2']
```

You might need to nest for loops and add a condition to test the depth of the keys in your dictionnary.